# DolphinDB Calculate the time difference between TIMESTAMP and DATETIME?

Tags: time, dolphindb

I tried the script in DolphinDB:

```
t =table(
array(DATETIME, 0) as MDTime,
array(TIMESTAMP, 0) as ReceivedTime
)
share t as testShareTable;
select * from testShareTable;
select avg(ReceivedTime - MDTime) as DelayTime from testShareTable;
```

The table is

[image]

But the output is not as expected

[image]

Any suggestions to modify the code? Btw, I'd like to add 8 hours to ReceivedTime. How can I obtain the result?

Answer (score 0):

Modified the last line of code:

```
select avg(temporalAdd(ReceivedTime,8H) - timestamp(MDTime)) as DelayTime from testShareTable;
```